# Postgres View / Function

Tags: function, postgresql, view

I am trying to create a view which joins 2 tables but the results are dependent on the query. Here is a example of what I want to achieve.

I have a table called **sessionaccounting** and a table called **sessionaccountingdailysplit**.

**sessionaccounting** contains all our accounting data and **sessionaccountingdailysplit** is the sessionaccounting data split by date. They are joined by the foreign key **sessionaccountingid**

How the two tables work in unison is as follows:

for the row in sessionaccounting :

> starttime - '2012-01-01', endtime - '2012-01-03', usage - 10000

for the rows in sessionaccountingdailysplit :

> date - '2012-01-01', usage - 3000
>
> date - '2012-01-02', usage - 5000
>
> date - '2012-01-03', usage - 2000

Now what I want to do is if I run a view called **vw_sessionaccounting** as

```
SELECT * 
FROM vw_sessionaccounting 
WHERE starttime >= '2011-01-01' AND starttime <= '2011-01-02';
```

it must only sum the first two dates from **sessionaccountingdailysplit** and replace the usage in **sessionaccounting** accordingly for each effected row. (most cases **sessionaccountingdailysplit** wont have a row as there was no split)

So as above if I run

```
SELECT * 
FROM sessionaccounting 
WHERE starttime >= '2011-01-01' AND starttime <= '2011-01-02';
```

I will get the result of

> starttime - '2012-01-01', endtime - '2012-01-03', usage - 10000

but if I run the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM vw_sessionaccounting 
WHERE starttime >= '2011-01-01' 
AND starttime <= '2011-01-02';
```

I will get the result of

> starttime - '2012-01-01', endtime - '2012-01-03', usage - 8000

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Why do you need the view? Why not use the last query if that gives what you need?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague in several respects. But from what I gather and guess, your query (view) could look like this:

```
SELECT s.starttime
      ,s.endtime
      ,COALESCE(max(sd.date), s.endtime) AS effective_endtime_max_2_days
      ,COALESCE(sum(sd.usage), s.usage) AS usage_max_2_days
FROM   sessionaccounting s
LEFT   JOIN sessionaccountingdailysplit sd USING (sessionaccountingid)
WHERE  sd.sessionaccountingid IS NULL  -- no split ..
   OR  (starttime + 2) > sd.date -- .. or only the first two days of the split
```

GROUP   BY s.starttime, s.endtime

#### Major points

- Use a `LEFT JOIN` because:

> ... most cases sessionaccountingdailysplit wont have a row as there was no split

- Only include the first two days: `(starttime + 2) > sd.date`
- Be sure to include sessions without spit: `WHERE  sd.sessionaccountingid IS NULL OR`
- Use table aliases to get your monstrous table names out of the way:
  `FROM   sessionaccounting s`
- `sum()` the usage for the first two days. If there was no spit take the original total usage instead: `COALESCE(sum(sd.usage), s.usage) AS usage_max_2_days`